# Gradle Shadow Plugin dependencies not present in runtimeClasspath

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I configure dependency using `shadow` scope added by Gradle Shadow Plugin:

dependencies {
    shadow "org.apache.flink:flink-java:$flinkVersion"
}

As per documentation, this dependency should not be present in shadow JAR (which is true), it should be on compile classpath (with is true as well), but I don't have this dependency on `runtimeClasspath` configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the documentation is wrong. Shadow builds jar from `runtimeClasspath` configuration, which makes it impossible to build different artifacts from runtime dependencies. https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/829647a06971ebc96c7d3df717f9a4e92811b602/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/ShadowJavaPlugin.groovy#L84-L85

Workaround is possible with intermediate configuration and redirecting `shadow` to contribute to `runtimeClasspath`

```
configurations {
    // alternative "runtimeClasspath" configuration to provide to shadowJar configuration
    create("uberJar") {
        extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get(), configurations.implementation.get())
        isCanBeResolved = true
        isCanBeConsumed = false
    }
}

configurations.runtimeClasspath {
    extendsFrom(configurations.shadow.get())
}

tasks.shadowJar {
    configurations = listOf(project.configurations.named("uberJar").get())
}
```